# Is a remote desktop session a background service

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtual-machine, terminal-services, performance-tuning

I have some virtual machines (xp, windows 7) running on hyper-v for developing and testing purpose.

I access those vms only by remote desktop and run on them various software

I was wondering if i could increase the vm performance setting the processor scheduling to adjust for best performance of background services.

[image]

Comment: No in your case, I do not believe that would help you. an RDP connection creates an explorer.exe desktop process, and all the per-user desktop apps load under it, so the apps spawned are not really any differant than if it were a local desktop instead of a VM. the RDP session may get more CPU time, but the processes you are accessing through it would be disadvantaged.

Comment: @FrankThomas this are also my thought.